# Netbeans javascript warnings for "==", "!=" etc

Tags: javascript, if-statement, netbeans, warnings

Every time I use an if-statement like "if (a == b) {...}" when working with Netbeans, I get these annoying warnings 'Expected "===" and instead saw "==".'
Is there a way to turn them off?

Comment: Why not just use strict comparison? ;)

Comment: Are you using a JSHint or JSLint plugin for NetBeans?

Comment: Do you have some JSLint/JSHint plug-in installed ?

Comment: No, just standard netbeans

Comment: This is an incredibly annoying "feature".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn it off in `Options` -> `Editor` -> `Hints`.
Then select your language and find it on the list. For JavaScript it's 
`Reports cases where in condition is used == or != instead === or !==`